# Nav Mesh Agentの切り替え方法

Tags: unity3d

以下の画像のような状況で，手前の赤四角をクリックすると赤キューブが動かせて，青四角をクリックすると青キューブが動かせるようにしたいです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

赤キューブと青キューブは画面をクリックした時に，クリックした場所に動くように設定しています（Unity本家サイトのマニュアル通りです[http://docs.unity3d.com/jp/current/Manual/nav-MoveToClickPoint.html](http://docs.unity3d.com/jp/current/Manual/nav-MoveToClickPoint.htmlhttp://docs.unity3d.com/jp/current/Manual/nav-MoveToClickPoint.html)）。

```
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveTo : MonoBehaviour {
    NavMeshAgent agent;    
    void Start() {
        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
    }

    void Update() {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            RaycastHit hit;

            if (Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition), out hit, 500)) {
                agent.destination = hit.point;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

上のコードに
・現在のプレイヤーを宣言
・クリックしたら現在のプレイヤーを設定
・現在のプレイヤーと自身が等しければ移動
を加えればいけるとは思うのですが，赤四角（Canvasのimage）をクリックした時に上のScript内で設定する方法がわかりません。

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/40546 マルチポスト

Answer (score 0, accepted):

他のサイトで解決したので貼り付けておきます。
https://teratail.com/questions/40546

> 私ならこうする、という一案です。
>   下記のMoveToClickPoint.csを、プレイヤー（実際に動くオブジェクト）とは別のオブジェクトに付与します。 
>   そしてImageではなくButtonを使います。これでクリックが取得出来るようになります。 
>   ボタンからPushPlayerChoiceを呼び出すようにすれば動くかと思います。

```
// MoveToClickPoint.cs
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveTo : MonoBehaviour {
    //インスペクタから、player1とplayer2のNavMeshAgentをドロップ＆ドロップしておきます
    public NavMeshAgent agent1;
    public NavMeshAgent agent2;

    //実際に使用するエージェント
    NavMeshAgent agent;

    void Start() {
        //初期値を設定
        agent = agent1;
    }

    void Update() {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            RaycastHit hit;

            if (Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition), out hit, 500)) {
                agent.destination = hit.point;
            }
        }
    }

    //ボタンから呼び出します。1を渡せばプレイヤー１、2を渡せばプレイヤー２をセット。
    public void PushPlayerChoice (int num) {
        if (num == 1 && agent != agent1) {
            agent = agent1;
        } else if (num == 2 && agent != agent2) {
            agent = agent2;
        }
    }
}
```